# What data structure should I use for hierarchical data?

Tags: data-structures

please help:

I have a data set need to be stored like tree, following is stucture, I am not sure how to store this, the letters are not comparable, this is just a hierarchic structure
[image]

Comment: if the letters aren't comparable, why use a tree? Can you not just use a linked list?

Comment: like a family tree I think, so linked list may not be good enough

Comment: Ah, I misread your description. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the picture, this just looks like a binary tree where only the leaf nodes contain data.  So, use a binary tree and only put data in the leaf nodes.